# Retaining only the Column Rows from chosen DF in the calculation results

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

This is a follow up question on: [How to treat NaN or non aligned values as 1s or 0s in multiplying pandas DataFrames](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45533971)

I have the following data:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({"x":[1, 2, 3, 4, 5], 
    "y":[3, 4, 5, 6, 7]}, 
    index=['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e'])

df2 = pd.DataFrame({"y":[1, NaN, 3, 4, 5], 
    "z":[3, 4, 5, 6, 7]}, 
    index=['b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f'])
```

I want to get the multiplication of `df1` and `df2` with all data in `df2` retained is there is no corresponding entry in df1 but only rows and columns in `df2`.

E.g.

```
print (df1.mul(df2).fillna(df2))
```

or

```
print (df1.mul(df2).combine_first(df2))
```

gives:

```
    x     y    z
a NaN   NaN  NaN
b NaN   4.0  3.0
c NaN   NaN  4.0
d NaN  18.0  5.0
e NaN  28.0  6.0
f NaN   5.0  7.0
```

But I want to arrive at:

```
   y     z
b 4.0   3.0
c NaN   4.0
d 18.0  5.0
e 28.0  6.0
f 5.0   7.0
```

NB:

- there can be legal `NaN`, `Inf`, `-Inf` values.
- columns / rows may not always be to the left or right / top or bottom of the resulting DF, though in the above example this is the case.

Answer (score 1):

I believe the easiest way would be to get the intersection of the index and columns, like this:

```
In [1142]: c = df1.columns & df2.columns

In [1143]: i = df1.index & df2.index
```

Now, just index and multiply with `df.loc`:

```
In [1145]: df2.loc[i, c] *= df1.loc[i, c]; df2
Out[1145]: 
      y  z
b   4.0  3
c   NaN  4
d  18.0  5
e  28.0  6
f   5.0  7
```